# Needed jar file's for add event google calendar in android?

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android. I need to know the needed jar file's to add the calendar event from my application and where to download that ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need any external JARs to access the Google calendar. For example, see this [article from Developer.com](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm). They explain how to put the right permission requests in your Android Manifest, and then how to query the calendar database.